# Mongodb - group() can't handle more than 20000 unique keys

Tags: mongodb, performance, timeout

I am running a `groupBy query` on my mongo cluster. I am using online [SQL to mongo query converter](http://www.querymongo.com/) tool. After running the query, I am getting an error. the data size is big. is there a way around?

```
// SQL  query
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM db_name
WHERE version="v2"
GROUP BY id

// Mongo query 
db.db_name.group({
"key": {
    "id": true
},
"initial": {
    "count": 0
},
"reduce": function(obj, prev) {
    if (true != null) if (true instanceof Array) prev.count += true.length;
    else prev.count++;
},
"cond": {
    "version": "v2"
}
});
```

**and I am getting this error**

```
 E QUERY    [js] Error: group command failed: {
"operationTime" : Timestamp(1589898357, 1),
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Plan executor error during group command :: caused by :: group() can't handle more than 20000 unique keys",
"code" : 2,
"codeName" : "BadValue",
"$clusterTime" : {
    "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1589898357, 1),
    "signature" : {
        "hash" : BinData(0,"SvsjmAIsn4rGwA/aRtLt3MPenJQ="),
        "keyId" : NumberLong("6784431306852794369")
    }
}
} :
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`db.collection.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) instead like:

```
db.db_name.aggregate([
    { $match: { version: "v2" } },
    { $group: { _id: "$id", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $project: { _id: 0 } }
])
```

The above aggregation operation selects documents with `version` equal to "v2", groups the matching documents by the `id` field and calculates the `COUNT(*)` for each `id` field.

As mentioned in [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline):

> The pipeline provides efficient data aggregation using native operations within MongoDB, and is the **preferred method** for data aggregation in MongoDB.
>
> The aggregation pipeline can use indexes to improve its performance during some of its stages. In addition, the aggregation pipeline has an internal optimization phase.

Comment: Yes, I tried this too. this is returning a `cursor iterator`. is there a way to know the result's count. I am only interested in the result count.

Comment: You can try `db.db_name.aggregate([...above options...]).toArray().length`